# WSO2 ESB, Api Manager - open connection after performed API (secure Kerberos)

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2, wso2-esb

I have a problem related to open connection after invoke API on WSO2ESB (4.9 and 5.0), WSO2 API Manager 2.0.

I have a REST API (endpoint) on my application. If I invoke this API directly on application with my credentials then it is working properly. But If I performed the same API call without any credentials (anonymous) I got 401 UNAUTHORIZED. This is the correct behavior. My application use IWA Kerberos.

I have configured API (endpoint) in WSO2ESB which points to REST API in my application. If I invoke API exposed from WSO2ESB with my credentials I get proper response and If I invoke the same API from WSO2 without any credentials (anonymous) I get the response as well. If I invoke this API without credentials after 2-3 minutes. Then I get  401 UNAUTHORIZED during invocation of this API without credentials (anonymous).

Moreover, I see in logs my application that two API call(with credentials and without) are performed with my credentials.

I don’t need authorization from WSO2 because I have built-in authorization from my application.

I tried set "property name="NO_KEEPALIVE" value="true" scope="axis2" for this API but didn't work also.

I hope that this description is clear :)
Do you have any idea?

Comment: Are you exposing your REST API from wso2esb?

Comment: @AnuruddhaLankaLiyanarachchi yes, I tried expose my REST API on WSO2 ESB and WSO2 Api Manager, I have the same problem.